# Pandas combines values from two columns and compare for uniqueness

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to combine/concatenate values from two columns of a dataframe and compare the uniqueness of these values, e.g.

```
      col1    col2
row1  val11   val12
row2  val21   val22
row3  val31   val32
```

I want to concatenate `val11` and `val12`, `val21` and `val22`, `val31` and `val32`, then compare `val11+val12`, `val21+val22` and `val31+val32` for uniqueness, i.e. to check if the three concatenated values are equal.

The `dtype` of `col1` and `col2` are all `str`.

I am wondering whats the best way to do this.

Comment: What are the dtypes here? and please define uniqueness, do you mean whether col1 == col2?

Comment: @EdChum I have modified the op to specify the `dtype` and uniqueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for checking uniqueness of concanecated columns `col1` and `col2` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print df
       col1   col2
row1  val11  val12
row2  val21  val22
row3  val31  val32
row3  val31  val32

ser = df.col1 + df.col2
print ser
row1    val11val12
row2    val21val22
row3    val31val32
row3    val31val32

print ser.duplicated(keep=False)
dtype: object
row1    False
row2    False
row3     True
row3     True

print ~ser.duplicated(keep=False)
row1     True
row2     True
row3    False
row3    False
dtype: bool

print df[~ser.duplicated(keep=False)]
       col1   col2
row1  val11  val12
row2  val21  val22
```

Comment: Thx for the code, I am wondering whats the name of this concatenation operation in `Pandas`

Comment: It is `sum` of string columns, I dont know  if it has special name.

Comment: what if I need to retrieve the boolean value of `~ser.duplicated(keep=False)` for each row, how to do this?

Comment: You can use `df['bool'] = ~ser.duplicated(keep=False) `